# Error when executing web service client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, testing, axis

I was trying the example in [JavaBoutique](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Axis/) tutorial and I get this error message when try to execute the web service client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.<clinit>(BasicHandler.java:43)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
at test.NHLServiceClient.main(NHLServiceClient.java:12)
```

Anyone know this error happen? I have imported org.apache.axis jar to my reference library. I'm using the wrong version or miss out other reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a class from [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/index.html), you probably need to add this to your classpath. You can download it from [here](http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi), but if you are using something else (e.g. Maven) you might just need to add a dependency.

Comment: You can also potentially add a logging bridge, ie, if you're already using SLF4J or LOG4J for logging, use a Common Logging to Log4j or SLF4J bridge library instead.  I tend to funnel all logging systems into a single logging library in my projects, as everyone seems to have their own preferred logging library nowadays.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem solved when I add reference to axis/lib/commons-logging.jar in the reference library :D